# Clean way to custom sort

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a `SELECT` request with custom sorts. Values on the `STATE` column can be `active`, `suspended`, `inConstruction`, and I need them sorted in this order.

I did something like this:

```
select c.id, c.state from client c
where other_conditions = TRUE
and c.state in ('active', 'suspended', 'inConstruction') --adding this for clarity
order by replace(c.state, 'suspended', 'b_suspended') asc
```

Doing this ensures the results are in the right order but it's really ugly. Is there a cleaner, more "objective" solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
select id, state
from (
select id
       , case when state = 'active' then
                   'A'
              when state = 'suspended' then
                   'B'
              when state = 'inConstruction' then
                   'C'
         end State_ord
       , state
from client)
order by State_ord;
```

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a045e40e99d41ba6ad5d8328ba4a5b87)

Or maybe with `DECODE`:

```
select id, state
from (
select id
       , decode(state, 'active', 'A', 'suspended', 'B', 'C') State_ord
       , state
from client)
order by State_ord;
```

You can use `case when end` and `decode` in order by clause too. One solution is already provided and the other is:

```
select id
       , state
from client
order by decode(state, 'active', 'A', 'suspended', 'B', 'C')
```

Comment: `DECODE`was exactly what I was looking for, but I couldn't find the name. Thanks! It's much lighter than `CASE`.

Comment: Hi @TeleportingGoat,  You are welcome I am happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: Note you don't need a subquery in the first two examples - you can order by column aliases

Comment: @ChrisSaxon but in that case he will have to show three columns...

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom sort like this:

```
order by case c.state when 'active' then 1 when 'suspended' then 2 else 3 end
```